# Header/Footers appearing in wrong position

Tags: html, css, header, footer

could someone tell me why the Footer appears at the top of the page, and I can't see the Header or LayoutDiv9?

This is the second CSS sheet I have added, the first is the Fluid Grid Layout CSS sheet that was automatically added and that I haven't altered at all.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#Header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 75px;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    background:#FFF
}

#LayoutDiv1 {
    position: fixed;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10002;
    background:#FFF
}

#LayoutDiv3 {
    margin-top: 105px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10004;
    background:#FFF
}

#LayoutDiv9 {
    position:fixed;
    height: 30px
    margin-bottom:40px;
    z-index:10006;
    background:#FFF
    }

#Footer {
    position:fixed;
    height: 40px
    margin-bottom:0;
    z-index:10008;
    background:#FFF
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: give bottom:0 to footer and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use `top` instead `margin-top` and `bottom` instead `margin-bottom` like this:

```
#Footer {
    position:fixed;
    height: 40px
    bottom:0;
    z-index:10008;
    background:#FFF
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `position: fixed;` but you're not saying where they should be. So it'll default to the top the page. Try:

```
#Footer {
    position:fixed;
    height: 40px
    margin-bottom:0;
    z-index:10008;
    background:#FFF
    bottom: 0;
}
```

But a JSFiddle might make your problem more obvious. http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

```
#Footer {
    position:fixed;
    height: 40px;
    bottom:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    z-index:10008;
    background:#FFF
}
```

CHeck the corrected code. I hope this will work for you,.

Answer (score 1):

Is your footer `div` below everything else in the html code? I think that'll do the trick